# Detect event.keyCode in Atom editor for Korean/Japanese input

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, atom-editor, keydown

Is there any way to detect a `keyCode` for `onkeydown` event for Korean and Japanese keyboard input in Atom editor?

This is really exotic, but I need to detect which key was pressed when user input is set to **Hangul** (Korean) or **Anthy** (Japanese) keyboard input.

Any other standard keyboard layout input gives desired key code (`q = 81`, etc.), but these input modes **always** posting `229` as event `keyCode`. This is Atom event subscriber I use:

```
// ...

editorView.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
});

// ...
```

And it works perfect for other keyboard layouts.

Another thing, I wrote native JS in HTML test page (out of Atom):

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
};
```

And in Chrome browser (which is I suppose behind Atom) it gives the correct `keyCode` even for Korean and Japanese input! Which means issue is Atom-specific.

Comment: atom is similar to brackets and when i wrote an extension listening for keydown, the brackets editor instance passes three args (bracketsevent, editor, key event) to the listener. have you checked to see if atom behaves like this as well?

Comment: @Cruiser: `KeyboardEvent keydown` object in Atom is same as usual event object in browser. So I suppose it's not the case.